# Does one side with a strong WLan antenna help both clients?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

In my appartment I don't have WiFi access in my bedroom. I don't want to setup further devices to increase my WiFi signal. Instead I was wondering if it would help to use a strong antenna + booster on my Accesspoint to increase the signal range?

Or in other words: Is it enough to increase the "signal strength" on one side (the accesspoint) to improve the communication with a client which has still the same capabilities or would it purely effect the send signal (accesspoint to end device)?

Comment: Please tell us the make and model of your access point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, without a full site survey and time/money spent on aerials, router positions etc. Far easier to buy a couple of powerline adapters and a decent access point to extend your range. A budget mikrotik hAP lite would be a very good choice (£30) & a pair of devolo 500 powerline units.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from probably breaching limits that have been put in place by your government, this is only a good idea if you upgrade the antennas on your devices as well. Because they need to send data back to your AP. If they may be able to receive a signal from the AP due to the better antenna, but the antenna of the device is not able to reply with a strong enough signal that the AP can receive the answer. So if this is a laptop or computer, you can probably upgrade the antenna with some effort. If the devices are smartphones or tablets, this is almost impossible for a common user.